# Create a tree of Observables and add a Subscribers as leaves

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have the following problem:

I am building an app which is filtering messages asynchronously. I want to build something like this, using Observables as filters(using .filter()):

input--filter1--filter2--subscriber1
      |__filter3--filter4--subscriber2
      |__filter5--filter6--subscriber3
                       |__filter7--subscriber4

Input will be a linked list, so I can create the observable chain using Observable.from(). Then I want to create a tree of observables as you can see in the drawing above. The problem I have is that I don't know how to broadcast the information to the next nodes for example: what passes filter5, emit to filter6 and filter7. This should happen for all the observables till the end of the tree is reached and I can have the subscribers which consumes the stream.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but you can simply create and chain Observables in your tree structure:

```
Observable input = ...

Observable o1 = input.filter(f1).filter(f2);
Observable o2 = input.filter(f3).filter(f4);
Observable o3 = input.filter(f5);
Observable o4 = o3.filter(f6);
Observable o5 = o3.filter(f7);
```

If you don't want to consume the input multiple times, you can `publish` it:

```
ConnectableObservable input = Observable.from(list).publish();

// ... chain as before

input.connect();
```